# prove that the unit circle $x^2+y^2=1$ is a closed set

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

I need to prove that the unit circle $x^2+y^2=1$ is a closed set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is closed using convergent sequence method.

Comment: So take a sequence $(x_{n}, y_{n})$ such that $(x_{n},y_{n}) \to (x,y)$ and  $x_{n}^{2} + y_{n}^{2} =1$ and show that $x^{2}+ y^{2}=1$.

Comment: @Nik Did you change your question? If you want to ask a new question, kindly ask a new question instead editing the original question.

Comment: @Nik I have rolled back to the previous question, since the answers answer your previous question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider the set $S=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\;|\; x^2+y^2=1\}$. Consider a sequence $(x_n,y_n)$ in S, s.t. it converges in $\mathbb{R}^2$.  We have $(x_n,y_n)\rightarrow (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ iff $x_n\rightarrow x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $y_n\rightarrow y\in\mathbb{R}$. This means that $x_n+y_n\rightarrow x+y$. Since $(x_n,y_n)\in S$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $x_n^2+y_n^2=1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Therefore $x_n^2+y_n^2$ is a constant sequence (given equality to 1). Since $x_n^2+y_n^2\rightarrow x^2+y^2$ we get $x^2+y^2=1$. Therefore $(x,y)\in S$. This completes our proof.

Comment: Why exactly do you have that $x_n +y_n =1$?

Comment: Because we are trying to show that for any sequence in the set that converges, the limit is also in the set. since sequence must be in the set we have $x_n+y_n=1$

Comment: Surely, it should be $x_n^2 +y_n^2 =1$?

Comment: You are right, doesn't change anything in the proof. You should feel free to edit it.

Answer (score 15):

Another way is to show that the complement is open. The complement of the your set is
$$S = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x^2 + y^2 \neq 1\}$$
Consider $(x,y) \in S$. For this $(x,y)$, the $\epsilon$-ball centered at $(x,y)$, where $\epsilon = \left\vert \sqrt{x^2+y^2} - 1 \right\vert$, lies completely in $S$. Hence, $S$ is open.

---

**EDIT**:
Here is a pictorial description of finding the open sets. The blue colored unit circle if your set $x^2+y^2 = 1$. The remaining white space is the complement of the unit circle. You want to show that this complement is open.

Now pick a point, say $(0.25,0.8)$. This is a point "inside" the blue unit circle circle. For this point, you can find a open ball of radius $1-\sqrt{0.25^2 + 0.8^2}$, which lies completely "inside" the blue unit circle and therefore lies completely in the complement of the unit circle.

Similarly, pick a point, say $(1.125,0.6)$. This is a point "outside" the blue unit circle circle. For this point, you can find a open ball of radius $\sqrt{1.125^2 + 0.6^2}-1$, which lies completely "outside" the blue unit circle and therefore lies completely in the complement of the unit circle.

In general, you can do this for any point not lying on the unit circle. This shows that the complement of the unit circle is open.

[image]

Comment: + 1 ............. For this pictorial presentation

Comment: _This_ is the way mathematics should be taught: long explanations, pictures, explicit examples.... My goodness. Then it is hard to _not_ understand it!

Answer (score 4):

HINT: Work in polar coordinates: then a sequence in $S^1$ is of the form $\big\langle\langle 1,\theta_n\rangle:n\in\Bbb N\big\rangle$, and you can think about it in terms of the sequence $\langle\theta_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$, which you can take to be in $[0,2\pi]$. (This isn’t the only way, but it makes life pretty easy.)

**Added:** Note that if the sequence converges to the point whose rectangular coordinates are $\langle 1,0\rangle$, this won’t quite work, since you may have infinitely many angles a little larger than $0$ and infinitely many a little less than $2\pi$. In that case use angles in the range $[-\pi,\pi]$ instead.

Comment: Good idea. (The 15 character limit for comments is stupid.)

Comment: It's ok, except for sequences oscillating around 0: there may be values near $0$ and values near $2\pi$, thus the sequence $\theta_n$ is not convergent.

Comment: @arbautjc: And in that case you shift the angles and work in $[-\pi,\pi]$, say. I was going to leave that as a bit of extra work, but now that it’s been mentioned, I’ll add it.

Comment: @Jyrki, no, Brian Scott is right, it's all about rotating the origin to eliminate the case where angles jump from $0$ to $2\pi$. Of course it's not very difficult to overcome, though a bit tricky.

Comment: Ok. Sorry about this. Reading your comment for a fourth time made it clear :-)

Answer (score 3):

The euclidean norm $$(x,y)\mapsto ||(x,y)||$$
is continuous then if $(x_n,y_n)\in S^1\to(x,y)$ we have $$||(x_n,y_n)||=1\to ||(x,y)||=1$$
so $$(x,y)\in S^1\quad \text{hence} \quad S^1\quad \text{is closed subset}$$